# How to make semantic-release do a release on a docs commit?

Tags: semantic-release

I started using `semantic-release` for some projects I have, is there a way to "force" a patch release on a `docs:` commit?

*Why on docs? Because it publishes on npm too and I want to have the latest documentation there.*

---

I also use dependabot to keep my dependencies up to date, should have patch releases for updated dependencies too, since a fix in a dependency is a potential fix in my project too.

Answer (score 0):

the plugin in charge of deciding if your changes should trigger a release is `"@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"` (no need to install it specifically), all you need to config is the `"releaseRules"` value:

```json
  "release": {
    "branches": [
      "main"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
        {
          "preset": "angular",
          "releaseRules": [
            {
              "type": "docs",
              "release": "patch"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
      "@semantic-release/changelog",
      "@semantic-release/npm",
      "@semantic-release/git",
      ...
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Thanks! What should I put the that config? Is that the package.json?

Comment: if this is a npm project, yes!